# Moving data between sections of Portable Executable (PE)

Tags: c#, portable-executable

I have a few questions regarding the structure of a Portable Executable.

Now, I found a great start through a couple of well written articles both [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx); however, I still do not quite have my answer.

I believe, and ***please***, correct me if I'm wrong here, that data in a certain section of the PE structure is what's loaded and run by the operating system. For example, take the `.text` and the `.data` sections.

Based on what I've read, the `.data` section holds instrunctions of some sort, while the `.text` section holds the actual data to be run.

I'm curious to know whether or not it's possible to store a file's data in the .text section, and dynamically move it over to the `.text` section which would then automatically (load/launch/run) the file's data which is now in the `.text` section.

If you are confused about what I'ma asking, allow me to paraphrase.

1. Where (in what section) is the *main* data of a file stored?
2. How would I go about moving data between sections in C#? I'm assuming I'd have to use pointers for this.
3. Am I correct in thinking that such a functionality would even work?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in thinking that such a functionality would even work?

No :)

It's not clear to me at all what you want to accomplish - you sound like you're talking native PEs because .NET PEs don't really have anything other than data in the PE.

In any case, the PE is mapped by Windows while the module (EXE or DLL) is loaded, so you can't really modify it on the fly.

Comment: Oh, and to clarify, for native modules, the .text segment usually holds the binary code while the .data segment defines uninitialized variables. Initialized variables (constants) are usually defined in a .bss segment.

Comment: I know this can be done though, I have seen apps that do just this. I don't think it's fair to say it's impossible ^^ ;)

Comment: Please, if you have the time let's continue this discussion here:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7254/pe-header-discussion

I will explain myself as best I can.

Comment: Alas, I'm only in here off and on between compiles and meetings, and so on :)

Comment: Well, let me know when you are back online and I'll send out an invite :)

Answer (score 0):

For native code PE or PE+ files these questions would be answered a lot different, and these things would be plausible.

However, for a .NET assembly encapsulated in a PE, things change a lot. **The PE/PE+ is just a storage container barely referenced by the OS loader.**

You *can* load into memory an assembly and execute it, so therefore what you propose is theoretically possible. HOWEVER, **it has nothing to do with moving code from one section of a PE to another**.

You would dynamically allocate read+write virtual memory, write your code to it, change the attributes to read+execute (adding execute, removing write), then invoke the appropriate .NET assembly loader code. Lookup the various Invoke methods for that.

Comment: Alright, that sounds like a plan then. So, using the above suggestions, I could run (inject) a file from within another file? So, by running file A, file B would also be injected. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that works. As the author of PECompact, it is how I implemented rudimentary .NET compression. An image of the .NET PE is compressed and embedded in a new native PE. I decompress the .NET PE, then 'run' it from memory (without ever extracting to disk, of course).

Comment: I'm assuming you wouldn't want to show a small example to start me off? :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I guess it depends. Are you a competitor? LOL. I hate to ask such questions, but in the past I have aided people, then they've come and competed against me - though that's nothing new to anyone, is it? Anyway, there is an open source sample on the Internet, I can tell you that much ;)

Comment: I'm nowhere near a competitor, heh. As you can see I have no idea what I'm even doing. Anyways, I've since moved on from this question. Thanks for the response though :)